# Overriding cursor value from parent to child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am stuck in between with this and can't figure out whats wrong.

There are multiple menus which are divs having some value defined. Some menu items are disabled/non-clickable and some are. I am differentiating between them by using `cursor` property.

If disabled, I set it to `cursor:default` and if enabled, I set it to `cursor:pointer` using classes.

Now, if any of the menu is clicked, It has to wait for a certain amount of time to load the page. In that time, I want the whole menu container to have cursor as loading. So I added `cursor:wait` to parent. Unfortunaltely, it is not working.

I also tried using `!important` but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var el = document.getElementById("main");
  el.className += ' cursor-wait';
  alert(el.className);
}, 4000);
```

```css
.container,
.container div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.cursor-default {
  cursor: default;
}
.cursor-point {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.container.cursor-wait {
  cursor: wait !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="container">
  <div class="cursor-point">Menu1</div>
  <div class="cursor-default">Menu2</div>
  <div class="cursor-point">Menu3</div>
  <div class="cursor-default">Menu4</div>
  <div class="cursor-point">Menu5</div>
  <div class="cursor-point">Menu6</div>
  <div class="cursor-default">Menu7</div>
  <div class="cursor-point">Menu8</div>
  <div class="cursor-default">Menu9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your CSS reads:

```
.container .cursor-wait {
  cursor:wait !important;
}
```

Which is looking for an element called `.cursor-wait` *inside* of your `.container` to style.

Since you're adding both classes on the same element, you need to remove the space. Additionally, you want to override the cursor on elements where you've already set a cursor - not on the parent:

```
.container.cursor-wait div {
  cursor:wait !important;
}
```

---

**Edit**: Per your comment:

> can I have something in CSS that applies to all child elements, not
>   just divs inside container

You can modify your code like such with a wildcard selector (asterisk):

```
.cursor-wait * {
  cursor:wait !important;
}
```

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var el = document.getElementById("main");
  el.className += ' cursor-wait';
  alert(el.className);
}, 4000);
```

```css
.container,
.container div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.cursor-default {
  cursor: default;
}
.cursor-point {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.cursor-wait * {
  cursor: wait !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="container">
  <div class="cursor-point">Menu1</div>
  <div class="cursor-default">Menu2</div>
  <div class="cursor-point">Menu3</div>
  <div class="cursor-default">Menu4</div>
  <div class="cursor-point">Menu5</div>
  <div class="cursor-point">Menu6</div>
  <div class="cursor-default">Menu7</div>
  <div class="cursor-point">Menu8</div>
  <div class="cursor-default">Menu9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your menu items has their own css specified an ancestor specification is not going to overwrite it. Just create a selector for the items themselves

```
.cursor-wait, .cursor-wait div{
  cursor:wait;
}
```

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var el = document.getElementById("main");
  el.className += ' cursor-wait';
  alert(el.className);
}, 4000);
```

```css
.container,
.container div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.cursor-default {
  cursor: default;
}
.cursor-point {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.cursor-wait div{
  cursor:wait;
}
.cursor-wait{
  cursor:wait;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="container">
  <div class="cursor-point">Menu1</div><span>some span</span>
  <div class="cursor-default">Menu2</div>
  <div class="cursor-point">Menu3</div>
  <div class="cursor-default">Menu4</div>
  <div class="cursor-point">Menu5</div>
  <div class="cursor-point">Menu6</div>
  <div class="cursor-default">Menu7</div>
  <div class="cursor-point">Menu8</div>
  <div class="cursor-default">Menu9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that is one option I had. Thanks. But menu container has div, img, anchor tags and even span as child elements. I'll have to specify css class for every element `.cursor-wait span`, `.cursor-wait a`, `.cursor-wait img`. Is there any simple way because If I add more elements some day to the container, I'll have to chage CSS again.

Comment: If only the divs have cursor set, then you can also add back the initial `cursor-wait{
  cursor:wait;
}`.

Comment: Actally no I can't. See @Jon's answer, it was a quick fix